# Using Reflection.Emit to set a property value

Tags: c#, reflection, reflection.emit

I'm building a dynamic proxy to intercept some methods within a library I am writing. I can successfully create my proxy type but when I try to implement the property setter I get the following error.

> System.InvalidProgramException
>
> Addition Information:
>
> Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program.

My Emitter code is as follows:

```
public void Emit(FieldInfo interceptorField, 
                 MethodInfo method, 
                 TypeBuilder typeBuilder)
{
    // Get the method parameters for any setters.
    ParameterInfo[] parameters = method.GetParameters();
    ParameterInfo parameter = parameters.FirstOrDefault();

    // Define attributes.
    const MethodAttributes MethodAttributes = 
             MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.HideBySig |
             MethodAttributes.Virtual;

    // Define the method.
    MethodBuilder methodBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineMethod(
        method.Name,
        MethodAttributes,
        CallingConventions.HasThis,
        method.ReturnType,
        parameters.Select(param => param.ParameterType).ToArray());

    ILGenerator il = methodBuilder.GetILGenerator();

    // Set the correct flags to signal the property is managed 
    // and implemented in intermediate language.
    methodBuilder.SetImplementationFlags(
        MethodImplAttributes.Managed | MethodImplAttributes.IL);

    // This is the equivalent to:
    // IInterceptor interceptor = ((IProxy)this).Interceptor;
    // if (interceptor == null)
    // {
    //    throw new NotImplementedException();
    // }
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, GetInterceptor);
    Label skipThrow = il.DefineLabel();
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Dup);
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldnull);
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Bne_Un, skipThrow);
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Newobj, NotImplementedConstructor);
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Throw);
    il.MarkLabel(skipThrow);

    // This is equivalent to: 
    // For get
    // return interceptor.Intercept(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod(), null);
    // For set
    // interceptor.Intercept(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod(), value);
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Call, GetCurrentMethod);
    il.Emit(parameter == null ? OpCodes.Ldnull : OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Call, InterceptorMethod);

    if (method.ReturnType != typeof(void))
    {
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
    }
}
```

When looking at the output code (A string property called Bat) using Telerik JustDecompile I get the following:

```
public override void set_Bat(string str)
{
    IInterceptor interceptor = ((IProxy)this).Interceptor;
    if (interceptor == null)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    interceptor.Intercept(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod(), str);
}
```

When using Reflector

```
public override void set_Bat(string str)
{
    IInterceptor interceptor = ((IProxy)this).Interceptor;
    if (interceptor == null)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Note how the last line is missing.

Any ideas?

Comment: Strange code, you don't want to return at all when the return type is void?  Write the code in C# first, look at the MSIL that it generates and just duplicate that in your Reflection.Emit code.

Comment: Have you tried saving your assembly to disk and running PEVerify on it?

Comment: Also, what is the return type of `IInterceptor.Intercept()`? Is it `object`?

Comment: It is. I've actually cracked the code below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out there were a few problems with the code.

Firstly as Hans Passant pointed out I was not returning in both circumstances.

That is fixed using the following.

```
if (method.ReturnType == typeof(void))
{
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Pop);
}

il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
```

Also, I am calling `MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod()`which will not work. I need to use `MethodBase.GetMethodFromHandle`instead and emit

```
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldtoken, method);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Call, GetMethodFromHandle);
```

To ensure the `MethodInfo` context is correctly pointing to the base type.

This all yields:

```
public override void set_Bat(string value)
{
    IInterceptor interceptor = this.Interceptor;
    if (interceptor == null)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    interceptor.Intercept(methodof(Bar.set_Bat), value);
}
```